# UIApplicationSignificantTimeChange notification is not triggered

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use the `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChange` to check when the day has changed and I encapsulated in my own class so I can easy use it in more view controllers:

```
public final class DayChangedObserver {
    private var token: NSObjectProtocol!

    public init?(handler: @escaping () -> ()) {
        token = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationSignificantTimeChange, object: self, queue: nil) { _ in
            handler()
        }
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(token)
    }
}
```

And I call this code from my view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    _ = DayChangedObserver() {
        print("Day has changed")
    }
}
```

I am testing this on my iPhone and I manually change the time. But it seems that it doesn't work using my class.

Is it something wrong with my implementation ? Because it was working when I was using this event in the past (without my own class implementation).

EDIT1:

I seems that `deinit` is called immediately after, so I am using an instance variable to keep a strong reference and now it's not `deinit` anymore, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`object: self` change to `object: nil`,try it.